# replacing complex numbers

Tags: complex

I know: I'm going to make a poor showing, but really I can't understand this:

`a` is an expressione whose FullForm is

```
Power[Plus[Subscript[u,x],Times[Complex[0,-1],Subscript[u,y]],Times[Complex[0,1],Subscript[v,x]],Subscript[v,y]],2]
```

Why does the following code return `True`, instead of the expected substitution ?

```
b = Replace[a, {Complex[a_, b_] -> a + H b}]
a == b
```

I have also tried

```
b = Replace[a, {Complex[a_, b_] -> a + H b},levSpec]
a == b
```

(even Infinity included) but without succeeding.

Thanks in advance !!

Comment: What exactly do you want `a` to look like after you've made the substitution?

Comment: `ReplaceAll[a, {Complex[0, 1] :> H, Complex[0, -1] :> -H}]`

Comment: Try, `b = Replace[a, Complex[a_, b_] :> a + H b ,Infinity]`

Comment: Sedai's , Jason's (see below) , and Evans's code (as far as I can understand) uses the same technique but ( perhaps, that's the very root of my failure ) I can't see why  RuleDelayed is indispensable. At a first glance, there is not much left to be evaluated after the rule has been used in his direct form. Please can you give any hints ? It seems to me that the answer isn't contained in `tutorial/ApplyingTransformationRules`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The original formulation was close, and the level spec of `Infinity` "almost" worked. As was noted in comments, it does work if `Rule` is replaced by `RuleDelayed`. The reason it otherwise causes trouble is from a "variable capture" in scoping. The pattern variables, `a_` and `b_`, have the same names as expressions under consideration. With `Rule` the rhs is evaluated immediately and the replacement becomes something unwanted. So yet another way to go about this is as below.

```
Clear[a, b, aa, bb]
a = Power[
   Plus[Subscript[u, x], Times[Complex[0, -1], Subscript[u, y]], 
    Times[Complex[0, 1], Subscript[v, x]], Subscript[v, y]], 2];
b = Replace[a, {Complex[aa_, bb_] -> aa + H bb}, Infinity]

(* Out[534]= (Subscript[u, x] - H Subscript[u, y] + H Subscript[v, x] + 
  Subscript[v, y])^2 *)
```

Moral: Be careful with pattern variable naming.

Comment: Now I see. Evidently, I have been, instinctively and erroneously, reasoning as I was defining a function ... 
Thanks !!

Answer (score 3):

```
a = Power[
  Plus[Subscript[u, x], Times[Complex[0, -1], Subscript[u, y]], 
   Times[Complex[0, 1], Subscript[v, x]], Subscript[v, y]], 2]

b = ComplexExpand@a /. I -> H
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming this is what you are going for,

[image]

You can get there two ways,

```
Replace[a, {I x_ :> H x, -I x_ :> - H x}, Infinity]
```

or

```
a /. {I x_ :> H x, -I x_ :> - H x}
```

Comment: I can't edit your post (characters). -I x_ :> -H x, you omitted sign.

Comment: Thank you, dude, for abiding.  (**edit** I want to make a Lebowski joke every time I see you on here)